# Third Normal Form Assistance

Tags: relational-database, 3nf

I have the following:

R = (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
FD = (A->B, C->D, E->F, ACE->G)

I'm struggling with the decomposition into 3NF.  I've read through several of the other posts and managed to confuse myself. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by determining all the candidate keys.

Answer (score 0):

The only key is ACE.

- R = (**ACE** BDFG)

A->B is a partial key dependency. R is not in 2NF.

- R<sub>1</sub> = (**ACE** DFG)
- R<sub>2</sub> = (**A** B)

R<sub>2</sub> is in 5NF. R<sub>1</sub> still has a partial key dependency: C->D.

- R<sub>3</sub> = (**ACE** FG)
- R<sub>2</sub> = (**A** B)
- R<sub>4</sub> = (**C** D)

R<sub>2</sub> didn't change; it's still in 5NF. R<sub>4</sub> is in 5NF. R<sub>3</sub> still has a partial key dependency: E->F.

- R<sub>5</sub> = (**ACE** G)
- R<sub>2</sub> = (**A** B)
- R<sub>4</sub> = (**C** D)
- R<sub>6</sub> = (**E** F)

All four of those are now in 5NF. (So they're also in 3NF.)